# Path wildcard not working in kubernetes ingress

Tags: nginx, kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress

I have installed Ingress and linked my service to it (usign metallb).

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: test-ingress
  annotations:
     nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /
spec:
   rules:
   - http:
       paths:
       - path: /api/tasks/*
         # pathType: Exact
         backend:
           serviceName: tasks-service
           servicePort: 5004
```

The thing is this, I set up the default prefix of the paths in the deployment to be

> /api/tasks/

where `/api/tasks/tasks` shows the service is up while `/api/tasks/tasks_count` gives the total number. However in my k8s cluster, I cannot redirect to the different paths within the service. What could be the problem?

Comment: As far as I know, path matching is longest-match-wins, so the `*` is implied at the end of every `path:`, and all things being equal, it's almost certain that you do not really want `rewrite-target: /` or it will literally send `/` to the backend service, since there is no capture group in use. Did you mean outside the cluster the URI is `/api/tasks/tasks` but the `tasks-service` should receive only `/tasks`? If so, you'd want `path: /api/tasks/(.+)` and then `rewrite-target: /$1`

Answer (score 3):

Since this is a result in Google for wildcards and prefixes, I'll answer this old question.

The functionality you're looking for comes from [specifying the path type](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress/#path-types) as `pathType: Prefix`

```
       paths:
       - path: /api/tasks
         pathType: Prefix
         backend:
           serviceName: tasks-service
           servicePort: 5004
```

Importantly, the path doesn't contain a wildcard character.  In fact, cloud providers like AWS will throw errors if you're using their [custom load balancer provisioners](https://kubernetes-sigs.github.io/aws-load-balancer-controller/v2.3/) for Ingress resources:

```
prefix path shouldn't contain wildcards
```